# How to Link to a Specific Section in Another Markdown File in Github

Tags: github, markdown

I have a question regarding linking to specific sections across different Markdown files within my project.

I am managing a project with multiple Markdown documents and want to create direct links from one file to another file's specific section (anchor). For example, I wish to link from document1.md to #section2 within document2.md, but the following syntax does not work as expected:

#section2 within document2.md

```
## <span id="ELB_concept">content</span>
```

document1.md

```
<a href="path to #section2 within document2">content</a>
```

When I click the link, it opens document2.md, but does not scroll to #section2.
How can I resolve this issue to make it work? Any advice or solutions are highly welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls use the file path and section like this: `path/to/document2.md#section2`

In document1.md:

```
[Link to Section 2 in document2.md](path/to/document2.md#section2)
```

In document2.md, where you want #section2:

```
## Section 2
This is the content of Section 2.
```

When you click the link in document1.md, it opens and scrolls down to the related section.